# Is there a Sitecore setting for which characters can/must be included in an autogenerated password?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

Is there a setting which can be used to specify which characters to use in an autogenerated password?

Our current passwords are a bit of a mess of special characters and we'd like to tidy them up a bit in future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a `Sitecore.SecurityModel.Cryptography.PasswordGenerator` class, which is used to assign random passwords to the security accounts installed by Sitecore Packager. It contains a property `Exclusions`, which is a string of characters to exclude while generating the password.

So, it seems you can achieve what you need like this:

```
var generator = new Sitecore.SecurityModel.Cryptography.PasswordGenerator();
generator.Exclusions = @"%|)(";
generator.Generate();
```

Answer (score 1):

When resetting passwords, Sitecore uses the `ResetPassword()` method of the `SqlMembershipProvider`.
By default, the provider that is configured is `System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider`.

I tracked down the code that generates the password and it has a hardcoded list of punctuations that are always randomly included in the password:

```
private static char[] punctuations = "!@#$%^&*()_-+=[{]};:>|./?".ToCharArray();
```

So you can't change this behaviour without implementing your own SqlMembershipProvider (at least not for resetting passwords, maybe it can be done for passwords generated by the packager as Yan answered)